# Limit of exponential and logarithm function

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

**Question:**

Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right)^{x^2}$

**Attempt:**

We can solve this limit by using the natural logarithm and the limit definition of the exponential function. Let's begin by taking the natural logarithm of the expression inside the limit:

$\ln\left[\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right)^{x^2}\right] = x^2 \ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right)$

Now we can rewrite the limit as:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2 \ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right)$

Let's focus on the expression inside the natural logarithm. We can use the Taylor series expansion for $\ln(1-x)$:

$\ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right) = -\frac{e}{x} - \frac{e^2}{2x^2} - \frac{e^3}{3x^3} - \cdots$

As $x$ approaches infinity, all the terms after the first one become negligible, so we can approximate the expression as:

$\ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right) \approx -\frac{e}{x}$

Substituting this back into our limit, we get:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2 \ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right) \approx \lim_{x\to\infty} -e x = -\infty$

Finally, we can take the exponential functio n of both sides to get the original limit:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right)^{x^2} = e^{-\infty} = \boxed{0}$

Therefore, the limit is 0.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes it is. Alternatively, you can use $$\lim_{u\to0}\left(1+u\right)^{1/u}=e$$
(proved similarly but more classical).

Comment: It's ok, but as a general principle, I would be cautious about disregarding terms after  the first in a series expansion.
Note that $$x^2\ln(1-e/x)=-ex-{e^2 \over 2}-{e^3 \over 3x}-... $$
and the second term is not negligible now.  Nonetheless, this expression still tends to $-\infty$ as $x\to \infty$, so the result is still the same.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio There is no problem in neglecting the terms after the first one. They *are* negligible with respect to it (i.e. the quotient tends to $0$, and not only the quotient of each of these terms but the quotient of their infinite sum).

Comment: @AnneBauval I understand your point, but respectfully, I still disagree with OP's presentation as a general principle.  Suppose OP had been trying to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} ex+x^2 \ln (1-e/x)$ and simply dropped higher order terms in the series expansion of the logarithm; then what would OP have done?  A careful accounting for asymptotic equivalences (e.g. using Big O notation) is of course valid, but that is not how OP's exposition came across.

Comment: The OP (uselessly) invoked Taylor series, in which these neglectings always follow this "general principle", like in the $x^2\ln(1-e/x)=-ex-{e^2 \over 2}-{e^3 \over 3x}-...$ where you said it does not. May be I trusted too much his skills. In this case, your warning and your complementary comment can be useful to him.

Comment: @AnneBauval Btw, how do you know OP is a "he"? :)

Comment: I [guessed](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1150701/orc-peon-gg123).

Comment: @AnneBauval Je ne suis pas si sûr du sexe, mais la description du profil OP semble rendre encore plus important de faire preuve de prudence pour les preuves mathématiques non rigoureuses !

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, your proof is absolutely blameless but alternatively, you could have used $\lim_{u\to0}\left(1+u\right)^{1/u}=e,$ which instantly gives:
$$\lim_{x\to^+\infty}\left(1-\frac ex\right)^{x^2}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\left(1-\frac ex\right)^{-\frac xe}\right)^{-ex}=e^{-\infty}=0.$$

Your approximation of $\ln\left(1-\frac ex\right)$ by $-\frac ex$ as $x\to\infty$ is classical but it does not need Taylor series, and should be denoted by $\sim$ instead of $\approx:$
$$\ln(1+u)\sim u\quad\text{as}\quad u\to0,$$
which [has a precise meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition):
$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}u=1.$$
(No need for L'Hospital for this limit, it is simply the derivative at $1$ of $\ln,$ by definition.)

And the asymptotic equivalence is especially designed to be perfectly compatible

- with products, i.e. if (as $x\to\infty$ for instance) $f_1(x)\sim g_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)\sim g_2(x),$ then $f_1(x)f_2(x)\sim g_1(x)g_2(x);$
- with limits, i.e. if (as $x\to\infty$ for instance) $f(x)\sim g(x)$ and $g(x)\to\ell$ then $f(x)\to\ell.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\lfloor{x}\rfloor.$ Then
$$\left (1-{e\over x}\right)^{x^2}\le \left ( 1-{1\over n+1}\right )^{n^2}={1\over \left ( {1+{1\over n}}\right )^{n^2}}$$
By applying the binomial formula we obtain
$$\left ( {1+{1\over n}}\right )^{n^2}\ge 1+{n^2\over n}\ge x$$
Summarizing we get
$$\left (1-{e\over x}\right)^{x^2}\le {1\over x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is basically correct but the asymptotic approximation can be made tighter as follows: $$x^2((-\frac{e}{x})-\ln(1-\frac{e}{x}))=\frac{e^2}{2}+\frac{e^3}{3x}+\frac{e^4}{4x^2}+...$$ $$<\frac{e^2}{2}+\frac{e^3}{2x}+\frac{e^4}{2x^2}+...$$ This last expression is just a geometric series with initial term $\frac{e^2}{2}$ and ratio $\frac{e}{x}$ If $x>0$ and the ratio <1 then the geometric sertes converges to $$\frac{\frac{e^2}{2}}{1-\frac{e}{x}}$$ which, if $x \ge 4$ is less than $$\frac{\frac{e^2}{2}}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=2e^2.$$ Thus$$\vert x^2\ln(1-\frac{e}{x})-x^2(-\frac{-e}{x}) \vert<2e^2$$ so $$-2e^2-ex<x^2\ln(1-\frac{e}{x})<2e^2-ex$$ Alternavely, you could take the limit of $$\frac{\ln(1-\frac{e}{x})}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$ as$x \to \infty$ by l'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @orc_peon_gg123 I deleted my original post with my snarky comment about your  asymptotic analysis and replaced it by another post in which I show how you could tighten your approximaton, which is essentially correct, to achieve complete rigour.

Comment: Complete rigor does not require such explicit bounds. The OP's approximation $\ln\left(1-\frac{e}{x}\right) \sim -\frac ex$ is fully justified by: $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ of the quotient is equal to $1.$

Answer (score 0):

One more way to solve:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{(1-\frac{e}{x})^{x^2}} = \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}{\exp(\ln((1-\frac{e}{x})^{x^2}))} = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{\ln((1-\frac{e}{x})^{x^2})}) = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^2\ln(1-\frac{e}{x})}) = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^2(-\frac{e}{x})\frac{(\ln(1-\frac{e}{x}) - 0)}{-\frac{e}{x}}}) = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^2(-\frac{e}{x})\frac{(\ln(1-\frac{e}{x}) - \ln(1)}{-\frac{e}{x}}}) = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{(x^2(-\frac{e}{x}))}\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{(\ln(1-\frac{e}{x}) - \ln(1)}{-\frac{e}{x}}}) = \\
\exp(\lim_{x \to \infty}{(x^2(-\frac{e}{x}))}\ln'(1)) = \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}{e^{-ex}} = 0$$