# Finding $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{e}{x})^{x^2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried using using the logarithm,
\begin{align}
L &=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{e}{x})^{x^2},\\
\ln L
&= \ln \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{e}{x})^{x^2}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln (1 - \frac{e}{x})^{x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \ln (1 - \frac{e}{x})\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln (1 - \frac{e}{x})\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln (1) \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln (1) \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \cdot 0 .\\
&= \infty \cdot 0
\end{align}
but get an indeterminate expression at the end.

Then, after some research, I found out about [Euler's number as a limit](https://www.nagwa.com/en/explainers/656149079142/), that is,
$$
e = \lim_{n \to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n
$$
and tried using both identities to see if one would work. However, after a substantial amount of working, I realised as the given limit had a **power** of $x$, there would always be some "residue" left:

Using the left-most identity:
$$
\text{Let $n = -\frac{e}{x}$, hence $x = -\frac{e}{n}$ and $x^2 = \frac{e^2}{n^2}$. So, } \\
\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{e}{x})^{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + n)^{\frac{e^2}.{n^2}}\\
\text{Since $n = -\frac{e}{x}$, as $x \to \infty$, $n \to 0$. So, }\\
\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + n)^{\frac{e^2}{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{e^2}{n^2}}.\\
\lim_{n \to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{e^2}{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}\frac{e^2}{n}}\\
= e^{\frac{e^2}{n}}
$$
If you notice, there's a "residue" variable $n$ left in the denominator of the exponent.

Using the other identity yields the same result: there's a residue variable left in the result.

I have exhausted every technique I know and tried researching for similar questions, but none that use Euler's identities have the variable in the exponent raised to any power. They all have a multiple of $x$, e.g. $10x$, or some linear expression $x + c$, e.g., $7x + 8$, allowing the end result to be some constant.

Any sort of help or pointing to some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Same](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652373/1118406) question asked this morning. What are the odds? :)

Comment: You can not seperate limit the way you are doing.

Comment: Oh my goodness... @SineoftheTime

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I have not learnt yet about Taylor's series but I will do so in an attempt to solve the question. @SineoftheTime

Comment: Is it because I moved $\ln$ into the logarithm earlier? So I can't express the limit of the product as the product of the limits? @Shinrin-Yoku

Comment: NO, in general the limit of the product is only the product of limits *if* both limits exist.

Comment: Right... thanks @Shinrin-Yoku. The limit of $x^2$ as $x \to \infty$ does not actually exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of exponential and logarithm function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652373/limit-of-exponential-and-logarithm-function) (You already said it does. This comment was just generated automatically by my vote for closing this post as a duplicate.)

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval, it does really well. I have submitted my vote.

Answer (score 2):

You have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac ex\right)^x=e^{-e}.$$Take some number $r\in\left(e^{-e},1\right)$. So, if $x$ is large enough, $\left(1-\frac ex\right)^x<r$, and therefore$$\left(1-\frac ex\right)^{x^2}<r^x.$$Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}r^x=0$, your limit is also equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks Prof! Truthfully I do not understand of much, but I still appreciate the response nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The limit can be calculated in an elementary way (no limit involving the definition of $e$ is used). Let $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then
$$\left (1-{e\over x}\right )^{x^2}\le \left (1-{1\over x}\right )^{x^2}\le \left (1-{1\over n+1}\right )^{n^2}={1\over \left (1+{1\over n}\right )^{n^2}}$$
By the inequality
$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ldots(1 +x_k)\ge1+x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_k$$ we get
$$\left (1+{1\over n}\right )^{n^2}\ge 1+{n^2\over n}=1+n\ge x$$
Therefore
$$0\le \left (1-{e\over x}\right )^{x^2}\le {1\over x}$$

Comment: Thanks Ryszard! My mathematics is still at quite an amateur level, but I will take the time to understand your working. Thanks!

Comment: I have added more explanations. All steps are elementary, should be available at amateur level.